# jQuery AJAX, getting variable from HTML data attribute with jQuery, then giving that back to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get the "data-postid" attribute from this HTML/PHP code, which I am then trying to use to get the unique div clicked which will then display the appropriate lightbox on click (I'm using a WordPress site, hence the Wordpress code):

EDIT: Changed the code to show current versions, and a new file called "myfile.php"

HTML/PHP Code (index.html):

```
<div class="person-row">
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID() ?> <?php post_class(); ?>" class="person" data-postid="<?php the_ID() ?>">
 </div>
```

JQuery Code (script.js):

```
var $post = $(this);
        var identifier = ($post.data("postid"));

        $.ajax({
            url: "myfile.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { postNumber: (identifier) },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

Then trying to get it back into the PHP to use

PHP Code (myfile.php)

```
<?php $post = $_POST['postNumber'] ?>
```

PHP Code (index.html)

```
<?php $PID = $_GET['postNumber'] ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If there is anything else you need to know I'll be happy to supply it.

Comment: At a glance, that looks fine. What is or isn't happening that shouldn't or should be? What has your debugging revealed about where things stop working?

Comment: You can change $($post).attr("data-postid") to $post.data("postid")

Comment: What does the `the_ID()` PHP function contain?

Comment: Please use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting to HTML to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Comment: I think you might have an incorrect name in you JS. Try `data: { postid: $post.attr("id") }` as you've used "id" as an attribute in your html instead of "data-postid" (attribute name instead of attribute value).

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. What's meant to happen is that the final PHP code should display the post ID, yet it doesn't.

@ithcy the get_ID gets the post ID from WordPress for use in the code.

Comment: In regards to debugging, everything is fine up until calling it back with the final set of PHP code, but it's just not displaying it at all

Comment: Mallander, where are you displaying the value that is coming back ? I hope you're not expecting the page to change, you're making an ajax request, you can alert the value coming back.

Comment: In all honesty, this is my first time using ajax so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. I'm trying to get the "postid" to use as a unique variable which I can then use to display a lightbox with the appropriate content for the "postid". How can I use the ajax $_GET that's being received in the final PHP as a printed number to use?

Comment: Mallander, look at my edit, add a success handler. The response will be sent back as an argument to the callback, then alerted. You can then make use of it.

Comment: The alert works, but it's just alerting me my entire HTML code back.

Comment: Then use another file, not index.php, any reason you want it to be in the same file ?

Comment: Well, surely I need to use "index.php" as the URL so that I can get the data of the "postid" from that file? The only thing I need is the "postid" of the div, which I can then use further down the "index.php" to display the right information depending on the div that was clicked. I'm confusing myself now.

Comment: @azizpunjani I've edited the main post with my new code and another file called myfile.php. Hopefully this can help you all figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not optimal, but in theory it should work. You can however improve it.

```
$post = $(this);
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: { postid: $($post).attr("data-postid") }, 
    success: function(response) {
       alert(response);  
    }
});
```

As stated by Misiur. You can change `$($post).attr("data-postid")` to `$post.data('postid')`. jQuery provides support for accessing [data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/) so there's no need to use `.attr`.

You were also had $post wrapped in a jQuery object, no need to re-wrap it i.e no need to do this `$($post)`.